# chrome extension notification messy code in Chinese

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am new in chrome extension develop. I got a problem recently, I have been searching the solution for a long time but i fail.
I want to show my user a notification ,which content is in Chinese, when somethings they might be interested in had happened. it looks like that:

```js
function showNotification(msg){
  var notification = chrome.notifications.create(
    '1',{     
      type:"basic",
      title:"Ad filter Notification",
      message:msg,
      iconUrl:"filtericon.png"
    },
    function(){});
  notification.show();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {
  showNotification("有电影更新！");
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request,sender,sendResponse){
  //if(request.greeting=="filtered"){
    showNotification("已为您成功过滤广告！");  
  //}
});
```

it worked,but not always,sometimes it come out like that,help me please!

[image]

below is manifest file:

```js
{
 "name":"Ad filter",
 "manifest_version":2,
 "version":"0.1",
 "description":"This is a Ad filter",
 "browser_action":{
  "default_title":"Ad filter",
  "default_icon":"filtericon.png",
  "default_popup":"popup.html"
 },
 "content_scripts":[
 {
  "matches":["http://dytt8.net/*",
   "http://www.dy2018.com/*",
   "http://www.dygod.net/*"],
  "run_at":"document_start",
  "js":["filter.js"]
  }
 ],
 "background":{
  "scripts":["popup.js"],
  "persistent":false
 },

 "permissions":[
  "notifications"
 ],
 "web_accessible_resources":[
  "filtericon.png"
 ]
}
```

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Could you include your manifest.json please

Comment: Does that happen on your machine, or does that happen only to some of your users but not you?

Comment: Actually,only a few of my friends help me to test it now,it happen to all of us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that your code is fine and that this has to do with your font encoding settings in chrome.

paste `chrome://settings/fonts` in your url bar and hit enter. Scroll to the bottom and under the 'Encoding' dropdown, select a Chinese encoding (see attached image).

[image]

[Here](https://superuser.com/questions/278640/chrome-extensions-and-popups-displaying-chinese-text) is a similar post for reference.

Comment: This is exactly what I looking for,thank you.and I found change the js file encoding can solve the problem too.

Comment: @zmychou glad I could you out! p.s. don't forget to mark this answer as correct, so others know for reference :)